# Cannot install Xbox One Controller Driver Software

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

Gizmodo released an article on how to use the Xbox One controller with PC. When I try to find the driver to hook up with the Controller, an error appears, "Access is denied". It happened to me when I tried doing it with the Xbox 360 controller.

Article: http://gizmodo.com/oh-sweet-you-can-use-the-xbox-one-controller-on-pc-now-1586549663/+whitsongordon

OS (Might not be needed): Windows 7 Home Premium

Error: [image]

Comment: Did you run the installer as Administrator?

Comment: "Home Premium" - most likely you weren't running it as admin.

Comment: @Frank It is not the installer, it is when I go to my Device manager and select Update Driver Software. It finds the installers files but that error appears.

Comment: @deutschZuid It is not the installer, it is when I go to my Device manager and select Update Driver Software. It finds the installers files but that error appears.

Comment: Yeah, but the drivers need administrator access to actually install, is my guess.  You might be able to get it working by running Device Manager as Administrator, but that's a sheer guess on my part.

Comment: @user74125 Device manager still needs admin access. It makes no difference whether you run an installer that comes with the driver or the device manager.

Comment: @Frank For some reason, I can only Open Device Manager when I search for it in my Start Menu. I also can't open it via Control Panel.

Comment: @deutschZuid For some reason, I can only Open Device Manager when I search for it in my Start Menu. I also can't open it via Control Panel.

Comment: @user74125 You can ping both of us by including two @ in the same comment. Anyway.. um.. can you be specific about about 'can't open'. it's all been a little vague so far.

Comment: It sounds like your running under a limited user.  Log into the default Administrator username and try to install the device.  Is supect this device isn't the only device you won't be able to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just got a Xbox one controller,you just simply need to download driver from here.

http://majornelson.com/2014/06/05/pc-drivers-for-the-xbox-one-controller-available-now/

or

http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-one/accessories/controller-pc-compatibility

i think so,this might help you!